# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str , doesnt work

Tags: python, pygame

This is the code ->

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

width,height = (500,700)
bg=os.path.join('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Python\\picture match','background.jpg')
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))



def draw():
    WIN.blit(bg,(0,0))
def main():

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

        draw()
main()
```

i have no clue why the error shows up, my previous projects have been working with this way.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bg` is a string, containing the filename, but not an [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. Use [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) to load an image from a file source:

```py
bbg_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Python\\picture match','background.jpg')
bg = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)
```

Scale the background to the size of the window:

```py
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (width, height)).convert()
```

Update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) after drawing the scene:

```py
draw()
pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

width,height = (500,700)
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

bg_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Python\\picture match','background.jpg')
bg = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (width, height)).convert()

def draw():
    WIN.blit(bg,(0,0))
def main():

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

        draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```